# Webbook using Latex

Tags: bibtex, wiki

I am looking for a web based platform/software to be able to create a math based webbook that can use LaTeX for formatting of text and equations. The webbook will be split up into chapters, sections and pages.

I want to be able to have the functionality of \usepackage specifically for amsfonts, amsmath, hyperref and graphicx. I also need to be able to use BibTeX for references and citations.

I have looked at WordPress and a number of plugins but have had mixed results in getting the web pages to format correctly.

I am curious if anyone has experience in WordPress to build such a webbook or if there is other web software such as a wiki or something else that would fit the bill?

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: TeX4ht has full support for LaTeX packages. It can either split one big LaTeX file into multiple HTML pages based on chapters, or create HTML files suitable for static site generators such as Jekyll or Hugo from individual LaTeX documents. It needs full TeX distribution to work though, so it is not that much suitable for servers.

Comment: Are you starting from a `.tex` source file and aiming to end up with html?  Then there are a few duplicates we could probably point you to.  Or are you wanting to have an html page that has LaTeX style syntax within it that renders properly?  In that case, the answer is likely "MathJax, and off topic for this site".

Comment: Take a look to [Bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/)

Comment: The content creators are working in PCTex or Miktex. The goal is to use some web platform to build the page structure of the website, and then on individual pages, be able to cut and paste the .tex document and have it render correctly on the website.

Comment: It is possible to use Overleaf linked to Github for online editing. The document can then be rendered using Github Actions. This method is using for example here: https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Introduction.html#x2-10001 or here: https://www.kodymirus.cz/overleaf-html-sample/main.html